# How do I increase the stereo mode volume of my headphones when they're already at max?

Tags: audio, headset, stereo

I have an MDR-1000X headphone and on opening the sounds option for it, I see two options to be used for the output audio: the Hands-Free and the stereo part (as shown in the image below). Now when I set the hands-free headset to default, I have no problem with the volume, and everything works fine, however when I switch to the stereo part, the volume is really low and when I attempt to increase it, I find that the volume is already at max. Any help in increasing that volume would be appreciated :)

(P.S. I want to continue using the stereo part because I found it to be much more high definition and detailed which is important in video games.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try enabling loudness equalization

[image]

(Image taken from [TechAdvisor](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-increase-maximum-volume-in-windows-8-3607915/))

Alternatively, you may want to download special programs like DFX Audio Enhancer Plugin (there are a lot of them!)